# Skinning the Android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I need to have mobile skins for the Android emulator, specifically for testing apps, for which I have referred this site: http://teavuihuang.com/android/.

I would like to have HTC 4G EVO skin. Where can I get one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need an official "skin". You just need to figure out what screen dimensions and memory capacity the device you want to test has and create a deployment target file.

Comment: i want to test application for HTC EVO then how can i make test for that model ?

Comment: @Paresh according to the published specs, the Evo has a 4.3 inch screen with 480 x 800 pixels resolution, 512 MB RAM and 1 GB ROM.